# How to represent this abbreviation in the acro package

Tags: acronyms, acro

I have the following abbreviation:

*TIS - Traffic Information System*

The plural form of this abbreviation remains as TIS although the abbreviated sentence gets the "s" in the end

Plural:

*TIS - Traffic Information System**s***

How can I cover this use case using the `acro` package for abbreviations

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example (MWE)? (By the way, I removed [tag:latex3] -- that's a separate topic which you can read about on the tag wiki.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in section 4.3 *Plural Forms* of the `acro` manual you can set a custom plural ending for a short form. In this case just set it empty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{tis}{
  short = TIS ,
  long = Traffic Information System ,
  short-plural = ,
}

\begin{document}

singular:
\ac{tis}

plural:
\acfp{tis}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I read the manual, but could not quite understand what does the `f` represent. In fact what does "first form; output like the first time `\ac`
is output " mean? can you expand explanation please

Comment: @KristofTak if you use `\ac{foo}` several times in the text then the first appearance prints something different than the further uses. The default first appearance is `<long form> (<short form>)` (but this is adaptable) while in all further uses only the short form is printed. In order to get the same appearance again as in the first time `acro` defines `\acf`.